# how to parent tag with nested tag using xsl

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML File that looks like this:

```
<root>
<SNS>
<SN>aaaa</SN>
</SNS>
<SNS>
<SN>bbbb</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
</SNS>
<SNS>
<SN>dddd</SN>
</SNS>
<SNS>
<SN>eeee</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
</SNS></root>
```

Required Output:

```
<SN>aaaa</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
<SN>bbbb</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
<SN>dddd</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
<SN>eeee</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
```

How to add every "SN" tag with "LN"?

Answer (score 1):

In first, the provided XML [is invalid](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp). It must be included into a root element. For example:

```xml
<root>
  <SNS>
    <SN>aaaa</SN>
  </SNS>
  <SNS>
    <SN>bbbb</SN>
    <LN>cccc</LN>
  </SNS>
  <SNS>
    <SN>dddd</SN>
  </SNS>
  <SNS>
    <SN>eeee</SN>
    <LN>ffff</LN>
  </SNS>
</root>
```

Then, if you want to output 
only descendants of an `<SNS>` element, you could use the following transformation:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SNS//*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```